# Deserializing YAML using YamlDotNet when the root node of each object is named using it's ID?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I'm using C# and I have a YAML file I want to deserialize.

I've looked at using YamlDotNet, and it looks like it's pretty decent, but I can't find how to handle this situation.

The YAML text I am working with has the following format:

```
1:
    id: 1
    name: foo
2:
    id: 2
    name: foo
```

I wish it looked like this instead, but it doesn't:

```
- id: 1
  name: foo
- id: 2
  name: foo
```

I can of course revert to doing everything much more manually, by looping over each node and manually creating the data object instances, but it seems like there should still be a way to have the ease of use from YamlDotNet while handling this annoying data structure.

I'm open to suggestions for other YAML parsing libraries in .NET.

Comment: Your ideal format is not a valid YAML file, you cannot have two keys with the same value in one mapping. More appropriate would be a toplevel sequence with mappings as elements

Comment: @Anthon Fair point! As you can probably tell I don't know much about YAML.

Comment: Would it be of interest to rewrite/reformat the file. Using Python and ruamel.yaml (of which I am the author), that is trivial, even preserving comments after the original  key-value pairs. You could even call the  python program to do the preprocessing from your C# code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's certainly an option. I found, and Antoine Aubry suggested, tweaks to the deserialization objects that will handle my case and I feel they're a better option for what I'm doing. But I'll keep ruamel.yaml in mind if I have YAML issues to solve in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer in another SO question: [Seeking guidance reading .yaml files with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095893/seeking-guidance-reading-yaml-files-with-c-sharp)

By deserializing to `Dictionary<int, Item>` I can successfully handle this data structure.

```
deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, Item>>(textReader);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a list, as your edit, you can deserialize that file easily using code similar to this:

```
class MyObject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
     .WithNamingConvention(new CamelCaseNamingConvention())
     .Build();

var result = deserializer.Deserialize<List<MyObject>>(File.OpenText("myfile.yml"));
```

Note: I am typing on a phone and can't test the code. It should be mostly correct but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I tried deserializing to a `List<>` but I got the following exception: `Additional information: (Line: 1, Col: 1, Idx: 0) - (Line: 1, Col: 1, Idx: 0): Expected 'SequenceStart', got 'MappingStart' (at Line: 1, Col: 1, Idx: 0).` Deserializing to a Dictionary<> works though ... which is what you suggested in the other thread I found. So thank you! If you want to change this to using `Dictionary<>` I'll happily delete my answer and accept yours (since you're the original source anyway).

Comment: The List<> is for your updated code, which is more appropriate to represent that information: `- id: 1 name: foo - id: 2 name: foo`

Comment: My ideal data is what I wish I had, but I don't have it. I'm stuck with the data the way it is. Well, not stuck, but I'd rather use Dictionary<> than mess about with transforming the data.